# Conveyor Belt Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm creating a website for a machinery company, specifically in the sale of parts - I want to make a cool conveyor belt style thing going across the entire page and behind a logo in the center, the effect I'm looking for is essentially what was done in this

http://codepen.io/Colir/pen/kIloz

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=1000 data-cycle-carousel-visible=6 data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true data-cycle-slides="div">
    <div class="span2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></div>
```

But I need there to be no gaps between pictures. Any ideas? I tried messing with the code they supplied but with no results. If anyone knows of a simpler solution please let me know! I literally just want the image to move left, pause for a second then keep moving and each image will be a bit of the conveyor belt with a part on top of it - this is the kind of image ill be moving along the belt http://s18.postimg.org/u2olj1plz/example.png

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add style:

```
padding : 0
```

to the `div`.

so the style becomes:

```
.cycle-slideshow  div{
    float:none; padding:0
}
```

See the updated codepen: "http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYmwYO"

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

Add this CSS. The gap is caused due to the padding from the class `col-xs-2`

```
div.col-xs-2{
  padding:0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/qf41ns7h/)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the padding on the `cycle-slide` class to 0 which will join each image together with no gap.

```
.cycle-slide {
    padding:0;
}
```